# Inserting Columns along with their Column Headers in VBA (one step)

Tags: excel, insert, multiple-columns, worksheet, vba

I want to write a Macro using VBA code that inserts both new columns & theirs headers in one sub procedure. I understand how to insert new columns into VBA. But what's the best method to insert New columns into a worksheet named (Sheet1) & name them too.

1. Insert New Columns into Columns B, C, D
2. Name the new columns

**Original Values**

Boston (Col A)  Chicago (Col B) Los Angeles (Col C) Seattle (Col D)

Boston (Col A)  **Nashville (Col B) Miami (Col C) San Francisco (Col D)**  Chicago (Col E) Los Angeles (Col F) Seattle (Col G)

Comment: Headers would be A1 , B1, C1 , D1 etc

Answer (score 1):

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Resize(, 3)
    .Insert
    .Offset(, -3).Rows(1).Value = Array("Nashville", "Miami", "San Francisco")
End With
```